# Jquery last element with LT Selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to collapse every element except the last one with this line of Jquery code:

```
$(".message_list .message_body:lt(:last-child)").hide();
```

Nothing collapses with this line. I have tried:

```
':last child'
:last-child
last()
:last
':last'
```

but nothing gives me the last element. How can I select every element less than the last element? What goes in the lt()?

Comment: Use `:last` and simplify your selector, maybe.

Comment: `:lt` takes a zero-based index, not a selector.

Comment: Surely .last() should work for this? http://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".message_list .message_body:not(:last-child)").hide();
```

Or depending on how your HTML is structured, you may need `:last`.

```
$(".message_list .message_body:not(:last)").hide();
```

Comment: In my case it was the second solution. Thank you for interpreting what I needed. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

[`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) takes a zero-based index as an argument, not a selector. If you *must* use `:lt`:

```
var items = $('.message_list .message_body');
var lastItem = $('.message_list .message_body:last');
var index = items.index(lastItem);

$(".message_list .message_body:lt(" + index + ")").hide();
```

Otherwise, use @Rory's answer.

Comment: +1 for answering my answer explicity. Went with Rory because as you guessed I shouldn't be using lt() in my use case in the first place.

Comment: Just covering all the bases. I would use Rory's answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".message_list .message_body:not(:last)").hide();
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/WnCeH/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample fiddle you could work from that may help conceptualize one way to approach your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/T5ZVE/

It uses .[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).